# Punch a user button!

Tags: script, fun

Gotten frustrated with a user? Want to vent? Feel like punching them?

Don't worry, here's a script that adds a "Punch" button to every gravatar. You can punch all the worst users now:

[image]

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/Punch-a-user.user.js). Will work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey). See [this page](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) if you have trouble, or want to install on Opera/Safari/IE.
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/SpecificStuff/Punch-a-user.user.js)

The majority of the code from this was taken from [this script by @balpha](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/70678)

Comment: Works in Opera too. Tested right now on your gravatar. :D

Comment: @toscho Ah, thanks. removed the "only" added a bit about userscripts on Opera/Safari/IE. _punches back_ :)

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @TomášZato just a bunch of moving images. Balpha created the animation, I just adapted it.

Comment: I hoped it will DoS their profile or somethin' :)

Comment: @TomášZato and others who don't realize what's happening: it's only doing something client-side. No users are harmed in the process.

Comment: @Mast It's you, not me, who's not realizing something - I was just obviously joking.

Comment: Does not seem to work for me. I disabled all user scripts to ensure there's no conflict, but still nothing shows up. Chrome

Comment: will someone who installed this post an image of it in action?

Comment: Yeah, it is broken.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer http://i.stack.imgur.com/YHLYt.gif Not broken for me on latest Chrome (linux)

Comment: err @sehe why me? of all the users? :-(